# Get date value from MySQL and insert into AlarmManager

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm making an alarm manager to notify users when to return their items. With the code below, I'm able to get the necessary data I need but problem is, it is only able to display. How do I store a value inside it inside a variable? I need to get the date so I can use it for my Alarm Manager.

I really need help, it's been nearly a couple of weeks. Please help me.

Do anyone know any other way to notify users by specific date? Please.

```
private class ParseJSonDataClass extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {
  public Context context;
  String FinalJSonResult;

  public ParseJSonDataClass(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void...arg0) {



    HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = new HttpServiceClass(HttpURL);

    try {
      httpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest();

      if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();

        if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

          JSONArray jsonArray = null;
          try {

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonResult);

            JSONObject jsonObject;

            Subject subject;

            SubjectList = new ArrayList < Subject > ();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

              jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

              String tempAuthor = jsonObject.getString("Test 1").toString();

              String tempBookTitle = jsonObject.getString("Test 2").toString();

              subject = new Subject(tempTest1, tempTest2);

              SubjectList.add(subject);




            }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      } else {

        Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

  {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(BookSearch.this, R.layout.custom_layout, SubjectList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
  }
}
```

Comment: you should be using push-notification for these kind of operations

Comment: How do I do that? Can the push notification read the date value in mysql and send a notification on that time?

Comment: you have to store all the data on some service, you can use firebase. also, if you want everything on client side, you can fetch the current UTC date from web and set an alarm for intended UTC date. let me know if anything is needed.

Comment: "on client side, you can fetch the current UTC date from web and set an alarm for intended UTC date" Can you explain further on that? I store my database 000webhost.